# the components in the error in x in the damped least square problem

Tags: matrix, regularization

Could someone explain for me why the error in x in the damped least square problem has two components,one from the noise on b and an approximation error from tau[image].

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens in the limit as $\tau \rightarrow \infty$.  In the limit, $x$ goes to 0, regardless of $A$ or $b$.  Thus $\tau$ is biasing the solution and you need to account for that bias.

Comment: so is this one components? and the other is when tau = 0, and it would be calculated the original equation Ax=b and the error is b-Ax?